# Pygame move shape with keyboard input

Tags: python, pygame

Created first pygame program to move a rectangle around the screen. Can't figure out why the shape is not actually moving. I had it working before with a simple

```
  shape = shape.move(speed)
```

But now with keyboard inputs the shape does not move. I used some print statements to make sure that the function checkKeys is rendering my keypresses (and the changes in speed that they make), and it is. However the shape still does not move.

```
import sys, pygame
pygame.init()

size = width, height = 320, 240
black = (0, 0, 0)
red = (255, 0, 0)
pygame.display.set_caption("Object Move Test")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def main():
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
    shape = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), (200, 100, 10, 10,))
    ballrect = pygame.Surface((10,10), 0, shape)

    def checkKeys(speedY, speedX, shape):
        key = pygame.key
        pygame.event.pump()
        if key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_UP] and speedY < 1:
            speedY = speedY - 1
            #print 'UP'
        if key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_DOWN] and speedY > -1:
            speedY = speedY - 1
            #print 'DOWN'
        if key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_LEFT] and speedX > -1:
            speedX = speedX - 1
            #print 'LEFT'
        if key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_RIGHT] and speedX < 1:
            speedX = speedX + 1
            #print speedX
        speed = [speedX, speedY]
        #print speed
        moveShape(speed, shape)

    def moveShape(speed, shape):
        print speed
        shape = shape.move(speed)
        if shape.left < 0 or shape.right > width:
            speed[0] = -speed[0]
        if shape.top < 0 or shape.bottom > height:
            speed[1] = -speed[1]

    while 1:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()

        speedX, speedY = (0, )*2 
        speed = [speedX, speedY]        
        screen.fill((255,255,255))
        clock.tick(20)
        checkKeys(speedX, speedY, shape)

        screen.blit(ballrect, shape)
        pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Probably only a partial cause of your problems, but you set your speed incorrectly. x =+ 1 means the same as x = +1 - you're not incrementing but assigning.

Comment: You're passing `Rect.move([speedX, speedY])`, but [looks like](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.move) it takes regular positional parameters.

Comment: @KarlBarker According to http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.move it sounds like the move method takes an offset.

Comment: @lmjohns3 positional as in `move(x,y)` instead of `move([x,y])`. I realise now the context makes that less obvious.

Comment: @KarlBarker Hm, yes, that's pretty confusing! I looked at the source to see -- it looks like pygame unpacks the list automatically for you: https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/src/823708f24a3a95381704a57f8e7ff4e532a8a05f/src/rect.c?at=default#cl-111

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with `pygame`, so this is just a guess. However, the thing that looks most like a problem to me is this line (inside the definition of `moveShape`):

```
shape = shape.move(speed)
```

The reason this is a problem is that `shape` is the name of a local variable within `moveShape`, but I'm guessing that you intend by the equals assignment to update the nonlocal `shape` object (the one declared at the top of your `main()` definition. When you call `shape.move(speed)`, the return value is a new `pygame` `Rect` object, which gets assigned the name `shape`. But this assignment happens inside the `moveShape` function, and so the update is not visible outside that scope.

It looks like you can replace this line with an "inplace" version (http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.move_ip) that will change the object without returning a new one:

```
shape.move_ip(speed)
```

Maybe that will work for you?

Comment: That worked! thanks! It was strange how it was working before. It would move when i pressed a key, but instantly reset to its prior position. I will spend some time to figure this out on my own. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Glad that worked for you! For background, try reading up a bit more on closures and scope in Python. Look for explanations of the `global` keyword, and (in Python 3.x) the `nonlocal` keyword.